# Find Django API Bottleneck

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, amazon-rds

I have a Django app deployed on Heroku with a PostgreSQL database on Amazon RDS. The React front end is deployed on Heroku.

In production, the API is very slow and I don't understand why. It's a small, simple database.

How can I figure out where the bottleneck is?

For example, I'm loading a page of 40 items and it takes 30 seconds. Even when I remove the actual query, hitting the endpoint and receiving a response can take 6+ seconds, which seems extreme. This load time is unacceptable in my app, and I don't know where to look to optimize.

Could it be RDS, or Heroku? I upgraded to the $25/month Dyno to see if that made a difference but it did not. No one is using my app yet so usage volume should not be a factor.

I'm not sure if this makes sense, but I threw some print() functions in my view to watch what section was taking the longest, and it seems like all my queries finish quickly, THEN it takes the 20+ seconds at the end to actually return that information to my React app.

Any advice on where to start much appreciated.

Note: I did install Django Debug Toolbar but I haven't figured out how to make it work for my actual API requests. It works for my admin panel pages (which are also extremely slow).

Comment: If you’re printing time stamps in your code, maybe also add a middleware function right at the end that prints a time stamp (at the top of the middleware list), look up middleware documentation in Django to see how to do that. Then you’ll know how long the request takes to be processed by Django (including DB queries). If that doesn’t take long, you need to look elsewhere. What’s your app server? uwsgi or gunicorn? What’s your web server? Nginx?

Comment: Good idea, I will try that! My app server is gunicorn, and I believe the web server is Nginx.

Comment: Set `log_min_duration_statement = -1` in `postgresql.conf` and reload. The extension `pg_stat_statement` can provide important information.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Okay, I set log_min_duration_statement to -1. Is pg_stat_statement related to this, or separate?

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake. I mean 0, not -1. It will log all queries and their duration. `pg_stat_statements` is not directly related, it can tell you which statements use the most time.

Answer (score 1):

The issue ended up being some Django middleware I installed called Silk. Not sure why it slowed things down so significantly, but once removed, my app probably increased 5X in speed!